# How to use Delaunay Triangulation to reconstruct the surface of point clouds?

Tags: algorithm, point-clouds

I have studied the theory of Delaunay Triangulation. In 2D, it does get a mesh from 2D points, and what you get is triangles. I wonder how to use Delaunay Triangulation to reconstruct the surface of point clouds. In 3D, the result of Delaunay Triangulation is tetrahedrons but we only need the surface triangles. Especially, I know some libraries such as PCL, CGAL. What puzzles me the most is CGAL's Advancing Front algorithm. It doesn't contain a process of projecting into 2D, but it does only generate triangles instead of tetrahedrons. I hope to get a answer.

3D Delaunay Triangulations result(tetrahedrons)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFLgY.png)
Advance Front results(triangles)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaDst.png)

Comment: I updated your tags, there is nothing C++ specific about your question.

Comment: If you ignore the internal edges, won't Delaunay just give you the convex hull?

Comment: I want to get suface triangles but not convex hull

Comment: Then Delaunay is not what you want. Do all the points lie on the surface, or there are some internal points that need be discarded?

Comment: All the points should lie on the surface. As far as I know, the result of Delaunay Triangulation is the convex hull of the input pointcloud. However , this is CGAL's introduction:'The first step of the algorithm is the construction of a 3D Delaunay triangulation of the point set.'   -from https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction/index.html

Comment: If you want to reply to someone specifically in a comment, please use @username notation. I see what they do in this algorithm. They triangulate the surface, not the volume, so it's triangles and not tetrahedrons.

Comment: @n. m. could be an AI Thank you for your comment. I am a new hand. Come back to the question,  and the surface point is still in 3D. The triangulation's result should be tetrahedrons. What am I getting wrong.

Comment: "the surface point is still in 3D" It doesn't matter. It is on a surface. A surface is a 2D object. It can be embedded in a 3D space but it is still 2D. Take a beach ball and a felt pen, draw some triangles on the surface. Here, you have a triangulation. You cannot draw tetrahedrons, and don't want to.

Comment: @ n. m. could be an AI
 Your latest comment seems to speak our goals again. I could understand what you mean, but what you said isn't Delaunay Triangulation  algorithm.  I don't know the algorithm that might be able to do what you said.

Comment: "what you said isn't Delaunay Triangulation algorithm" The resulting triangles are Delaunay triangles, so the *result of the algorithm is* a Delaunay triangulation. To run the normal Delaunay triangulation algorithm on a surface you would need a surface to begin with. They are building a surface, triangle by triangle, so the algorithm is a different one.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!@
n. m. could be an AI